# Categorise measures to use as dimension

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I am trying to build a table where I am summing multiple measures and would like to categorise them into dimensions.

To simplify, I have a table in the warehouse with the below schema:

```
Profitability(month_end_date, product_type, existing_direct_variable_expenses, existing_direct_fixed_expenses, existing_indirect_expenses, new_direct_variable_expenses, new_direct_fixed_expenses)
```

In my measure I am summing *existing_direct_variable_expenses, existing_direct_fixed_expenses, existing_indirect_expenses, new_direct_variable_expenses, new_direct_fixed_expenses* for one specific product for a date filtered by the user.

I would like to display the below output

Expense   | Amount

existing_direct_variable_expenses | 1,000

existing_direct_fixed_expenses | 200

existing_indirect_expenses | 1,500

new_direct_variable_expenses | 500

new_direct_fixed_expenses |50

I have tried to categorise it using the below formula, however it doesn't get past the first condition since each line has a value in each column in the dataset

```
if(NOT ISNULL(existing_direct_variable_expenses), 'Existing Direct Variable Expenses', 
    if(NOT ISNULL(existing_direct_fixed_expenses), 'Existing Direct Fixed Expenses',
        if(NOT ISNULL(existing_indirect_expenses), 'Existing Indirect Expenses',
            if(NOT ISNULL(new_direct_variable_expenses), 'New Direct Variable Expenses',
                if(NOT ISNULL(new_direct_fixed_expenses), 'New Direct Fixed Expenses')))))
```

I also had a play with AGGR function but had no luck.

I realise I could display as measures, however I will also be doing a column for Year To Date expenses and would like to maintain consistency along the other areas of my dashboard by having one column for a month and the breakdown as a dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For references sake, I was able to complete the issue with a [Value List](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2020/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/ChartFunctions/SyntheticDimensionFunctions/valuelist.htm). I added the below in my table as a dimension to display the categories:

```
=valuelist('Existing Direct Variable Expenses', 'Existing Direct Fixed Expenses', 'Existing Indirect Expenses', 'New Direct Variable Expenses', 'New Direct Fixed Expenses')
```

I then added this into my measure to correctly sum the values against each of the dimensions.

```
if(valuelist('Existing Direct Variable Expenses', 'Existing Direct Fixed Expenses', 'Existing Indirect Expenses', 'New Direct Variable Expenses', 'New Direct Fixed Expenses')='Existing Direct Variable Expenses',
    sum({<product_type={'Sales'}>} existing_direct_variable_expenses),
if(valuelist('Existing Direct Variable Expenses', 'Existing Direct Fixed Expenses', 'Existing Indirect Expenses', 'New Direct Variable Expenses', 'New Direct Fixed Expenses')='Existing Direct Fixed Expenses',
    sum({<product_type={'Sales'}>} existing_direct_fixed_expenses),
if(valuelist('Existing Direct Variable Expenses', 'Existing Direct Fixed Expenses', 'Existing Indirect Expenses', 'New Direct Variable Expenses', 'New Direct Fixed Expenses')='Existing Indirect Expenses',
    sum({<product_type={'Sales'}>} existing_indirect_expenses),
if(valuelist('Existing Direct Variable Expenses', 'Existing Direct Fixed Expenses', 'Existing Indirect Expenses', 'New Direct Variable Expenses', 'New Direct Fixed Expenses')='New Direct Variable Expenses',
    sum({<product_type={'Sales'}>} new_direct_variable_expenses),
if(valuelist('Existing Direct Variable Expenses', 'Existing Direct Fixed Expenses', 'Existing Indirect Expenses', 'New Direct Variable Expenses', 'New Direct Fixed Expenses')='New Direct Fixed Expenses',
    sum({<product_htype={'Sales'}>} new_direct_fixed_expenses))))))
```